# Keras fit_generator: random augmentation inside the generator + shuffling

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have created a generator to input it in the `fit_generator` function of keras. The generator creates some random values. This is how I have done it:

```
class DataGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, X_Y_file_path, batch_size, N):
        self.X_Y_file_path = X_Y_file_path
        self.batch_size = size
        self.N = N

    def initialize_zeros(self):
        X = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1), dtype='int32')
        Y = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1), dtype='int32')
        Y_neg = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.N))
        return X, Y, Y_neg

     def generate(self):
        while True:
            i = 0 
            X, Y, Y_neg = initialize_zeros()
            for row in load_data_per_line(self.X_Y_file_path): # load_data_per_line is generator function which goes each line at a time from one file.
                x, y = row
                y_neg = random.sample(id_list, self.N) # a list of id to pick randomly
                X[i] = x
                Y[i] = y
                Y_neg[i] = y_neg
                if i == self.batch_size:
                    yield ([X, Y_neg], Y) # Y_neg goes as input in the model.(not important here. just mentioning)
                    X, Y, Y_neg = initialize_zeros()
                    i = 0
```

So this is my generator. With same sample data it seems its working correctly though.

I was wondering how can I implement in this generator a shuffle function to shuffle after each epoch?

Searching a bit I found out about [Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) which you can override `on_epoch_end` method but it is not clear how I can implement the above generator with `Sequence` inheritance. Any help on that? (btw is the above function 'safe' to use `use_multiprocessing` in `fit_generator`?)

**Edit**

The `X_Y_file_path` is one file(with known length).
The `load_data_per_line` is a generator function which yields one per line.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track to use a Sequence. It will guarantee that every data point is seen once when used with multi-processing. An easy way to construct the Sequence is preload the raw data, do on the fly processing every time a batch is requested.

```
class MySeq(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, X_Y_file_path, batch_size, N):
        self.X_Y_file_path = X_Y_file_path
        self.batch_size = size
        self.N = N
        self.data = load_data_per_line(self.X_Y_file_path)

     def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.data) / self.batch_size))

     def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Just slice the data based on batch index (idx)
        batch_data = self.data[idx*self.batch_size:(idx+1)*self.batch_size]
        X = np.zeros((len(batch_data), 1), dtype='int32')
        Y = np.zeros((len(batch_data), 1), dtype='int32')
        Y_neg = np.zeros((len(batch_data), self.N))
        for row, i in enumerate(data):
            x, y = row
            y_neg = random.sample(id_list, self.N) # a list of id to pick randomly
            X[i] = x
            Y[i] = y
            Y_neg[i] = y_neg
        return [X, Y_neg], Y # This is a single batch
```

Now you can perform any processing on your `self.data` using `on_epoch_end()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What you write here is a copy-paste of the example in the documentation. And it will not work for my case that provided in the question.